# Codeigniter MySQL JOIN Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im a beginner in MySQL, I got a hard time joining 2 tables in Codeigniter. So let me explain my tables.

In the first table named forum_topic I got these columns

topic_id topic_sk topic_subject topic_desc posted_by date_posted 
1 123Qwe Rules and Regulations Anything Jonas Dulay 2015-11-03 11:15 PM 

The second table is named forum_comment 
comment_id topic_sk 
1 123Qwe  
2 123Qwe 

The expected result will be like this

Topics Replies Date Posted by
Rules and Regulation 2 2015-11-03 11:15 PM Jonas Dulay

I dont know the process of getting the count of number of comment in other table 
then join it . This is my query but it seems it  will not help you.

```
    $this->db->select('*,count(forum_comment.topic_sk) as count');
    $this->db->from('forum_topic');
    $this->db->where(array('f_cat_id'=>$cat,'topic_status'=>1))
    ->join('forum_comment','forum_comment.topic_sk = forum_topic.topic_sk','left')
    ->group_by('forum_topic.topic_sk');

    $this->db->order_by('pinned',"DESC");
    $this->db->order_by("date_posted","DESC");

    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: Please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695503/codeigniter-counting-results-from-a-joined-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below query, I think this is useful for you:

```
$this->db->select('ft.*,', FALSE);
 $this->db->select('IFNULL(COUNT(fc.topic_sk),0) as count', FALSE);
 $this->db->from('forum_topic as ft');
 $this->db->join("forum_comment as fc", ' rc.topic_sk = ft.topic_sk','left');
 $this->db->group_by('ft.topic_sk');
 $this->db->order_by('pinned',"DESC");
 $this->db->order_by("date_posted","DESC");

 $query= $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

Comment: May i ask for an explanation ? I want to learn it specially the part on IFNULL

Comment: IFNULL check to value of column given, If column value is null then return count is 0. This is used for check column value null or not. If you want to learn CI Please see this link : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html