# How to count the total Comments and total Likes using joined tables in codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am attempting to get all of the posts inside my social media database.

It's retrieve all list of post the user information, comments and likes.

Now I have successfully retrieved the total comments of each post but having trouble counting all likes of each post.

Here is my code so far.

```html
<?php

public function get_all_post(){

  $category = $this->input->post('category', true);
  
  $this->db->select('u.*,c.parent_id,b.post_id, count(b.ID) as total, count(c.ID) as totalLIKEs');
  $this->db->where('u.category', $category);
  $this->db->order_by("u.create_at", "DESC")
  ->from('gb_post as u')
  ->join('gb_comments as b', 'u.ID = b.post_id', 'LEFT')
  ->join('gb_likes as c', 'u.ID = c.parent_id', 'LEFT')
  ->group_by('u.ID');
  
  $this->db->limit(10);
  $result = $this->db->get();

  if($result->num_rows() > 0){
    return $result->result_array();
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
?>
```

Here is my SQL tables

Post table

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| ID | post_content  |   user_email    |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
|  1 | post1         | user1@email.com |
|  2 | post2         | user2@email.com |
|  3 | post3         | user3@email.com |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment Table

```
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
| ID | post_id | comment_content |   reader_email    |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
|  1 |       3 | test comment1   | reader1@email.com |
|  2 |       3 | test comment2   | reader2@email.com |
|  3 |       2 | test comment3   | reader3@email.com |
|  4 |       1 | test comment4   | reader3@email.com |
+----+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

And my Likes Table

```
+----+----------+-------------------+
| ID | post_id  |   reader_email    |
+----+----------+-------------------+
|  1 |        3 | reader1@email.com |
|  2 |        3 | reader2@email.com |
|  3 |        3 | reader7@email.com |
|  4 |        3 | reader3@email.com |
+----+----------+-------------------+
```

Example the post with the ID of 3 will have a total of 2 comments and 4 likes.

The problem is the count of **`totalComment`** is also the count of **`totalLIKEs`**

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm seeing here but I would advise to change this question into a generic SQL one where much more people would be able to help. Try to add a sample of the table itself, and replace the PHP code with the SQL query. Stripping extra information makes it easier for you to locate the problem, and for others to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: Counting results from a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695503/codeigniter-counting-results-from-a-joined-table)